# Iterate over two strings checking to see if it matches with its pair

Tags: java, string, charat

I am still new to Java, and I am currently working on a program that will take two strings as arguments and return the number of mismatched pairs. For my program I am working with ATGC because in science, A's always match up with T's and G's always match up with C's. I cant quite figure out how to iterate over the strings and see that the first character in string one (T for example) matches up with its intended pair (A), and if it doesn't it is a mismatched pair and it should be added to a counter to be totaled at the end. I believe I can use something called charAt(), but I am unsure of how that works.

I also need to figure out how to be able to take the absolute value of counter before it is added to the finalCounter. The main reason for this is because I just want to worry about getting the length difference between the two rather than making sure that the longer string is subracted from the smaller string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

''''

```
    public class CountMismatches {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            {
                String seq1 = "TTCGATGGAGCTGTA";
                String seq2 = "TAGCTAGCTCGGCATGA";
                System.out.println(count_mismatches(seq1, seq2))
                //*expected to print out 5 because there are 3 mismatched pairs and 2 that do not have a pair*
            }
        }

        public static int count_mismatches(String seq1, String seq2) {
            int mismatchCount = 0;
            int counter = seq1.length() - seq2.length();
            int finalCounter = mismatchCount + counter;

            for(int i = 0; i < seq1.length(); i++) if (seq1.charAt(i) == seq2.charAt(i)) {
                break; //checks to see if the length of seq1 and seq2 are the same
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < seq1.length(); i++) if (seq1.charAt(i) != seq2.charAt(i)) {
                return counter; //figure out how to do absolute value for negative numbers
            }
            return finalCounter;

        }
    }
```

'''

Comment: will the length on seq1 and seq2 be always same?

Comment: It can be the same but it won't always be the same.

Comment: do you need to store the counter separately ? or only finalCounter matters?

Comment: They don't need to be stored separately, but I figured it would be easier to see if I had a finalCounter.

Comment: `counter` should contain the two extra counts already because you calculate the difference when you use `seq1.length() - seq2.length();`. All you need to do is loop to the end of the shortest string while using if statements to determine if the two pairs are intended pairs.

Comment: You should have a helper method that accepts the two chars and determines if they match up and increments count otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to count only the places where there are differences, you can iterate through the minimum length present in both the strings and find out the places where they are different.
In the end, you can add absolute difference of length between seq1 and seq2 and return that value to the main function.
For the logic, all you have to do is apply 4 if conditions to check if character is A,G,C,T and if suitable pair is present in the other string.

```
public class CountMismatches {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            String seq1 = "TTCGATGGAGCTGTA";
            String seq2 = "TAGCTAGCTCGGCATGA";

            System.out.println(count_mismatches(seq1, seq2));

        }
    }

    public static int count_mismatches(String seq1, String seq2) {

        int finalCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(seq1.length(), seq2.length()); i++) {
            char c1 = seq1.charAt(i);

            char c2 = seq2.charAt(i);

            if (c1 == 'A') {
                if (c2 == 'T')
                    continue;
                else
                    finalCounter++;

            } else if (c1 == 'T') {
                if (c2 == 'A')
                    continue;
                else
                    finalCounter++;
            } else if (c1 == 'G') {
                if (c2 == 'C')
                    continue;
                else
                    finalCounter++;
            } else if (c1 == 'C') {
                if (c2 == 'G')
                    continue;
                else
                    finalCounter++;
            } 
        }
        return finalCounter + (Math.abs(seq1.length() - seq2.length()));

    }
}
```

and the output is as follows :

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these refactorings:

- To make the comparisons easy to code and understand, create a `Map` whose entires are each pair (both directions)
- Iterate over the Strings up to the length of the shortest one, adding up the number of matching pairs as you go
- The result is the length of the longest String minus the number of pairs

Like this:

```
public static int count_mismatches(String seq1, String seq2) {
    Map<Character, Character> pairs = Map.of('A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'G');
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(seq1.length(), seq2.length()); i++) {
        if (pairs.get(seq1.charAt(i)) == seq2.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return Math.max(seq1.length(), seq2.length()) - count;
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/o4fByt), which returns `5` for your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Good Evening,

Something seems off here, this snippet of code:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < seq1.length(); i++)
       if (seq1.charAt(i) == seq2.charAt(i)) {
           break; //checks to see if the length of seq1 and seq2 are the same
       }
```

Does not do what you think it does. This cycle will loop through all characters in sequence1 using `i < seq1.length()` and for each character that exists in `seq1`, it will check if said character is equal to the character with the same index in `seq2`.

This means that a correction is in order:

```
int countMismatches = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < seq1.length();i++){
   switch(seq1.charAt(i)){
      case 'A':
         if(seq2.charAt(i) != 'T') countMismatches++;
         break;
   }
 }
```

Repeat this process for the other letters, and voilá, you should be able to count your mismatches this way.

Do be careful with sequences having different lengths, as if that happens, as soon as you step out of a bound, you will receive an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, indicating you've tried to check a character that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid `char`

The `char` type is legacy, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. The `char` type in your particular case would work. But using `char` is a bad habit generally, as such code may break when encountering any of about 75,000 characters defined in Unicode.

## Code point

Use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead. A code point is the number assigned to each of the over 140,000 characters defined by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium).

Here we get an `IntStream`, a series of `int` values, one for each character in the input string. Then we collect these integer numbers into an array of `int` values.

```
int[] codePoints1 = seq1.codePoints().toArray() ;
int[] codePoints2 = seq2.codePoints().toArray() ;
```

You said the input strings may be of unequal length. So our two arrays may be jagged, of different lengths. Figure out the size of the shorter array.

```
int smallerSize = Math.min( codePoints1.length , codePoints2.length ) ;
```

Keep track of the index number of mismatched rows.

```
List<Integer> mismatchIndices = new ArrayList <>();
```

Loop the arrays based on that smaller size.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < smallerSize ; i ++ )
{
    if ( isBasePairValid( codePoint first , codePoint second ) )
    {
        … 
    } else 
    {
        mismatchIndices.add( i ) ;
    }
}
```

## Write an `isBasePairValid` method

Write the `isBasePairValid` method, taking two arguments, the code points of the two [nucleobase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleobase) letters.

```java
static int A = "A".codePointAt( 0 ) ;  // Annoying zero-based index counting. So first character is number zero. 
static int C = "C".codePointAt( 0 ) ;
static int G = "G".codePointAt( 0 ) ;
static int T = "T".codePointAt( 0 ) ;

if( first == A ) return ( second == T ) 
else if( first == T ) return ( second == A ) 
else if( first == C ) return ( second == G ) 
else if( first == G ) return ( second == C ) 
else { throw new IllegalStateException( … ) ; }
```

Count the mismatches.

```
int countMismatches = mismatchIndices.size() ;
```

Comment: You've mentioned this in several past answers related to the usage of the `char` type.  It would seem that those responsible for evolution of the language would see fit to deprecate character related methods.

Comment: @WJS The text-handling facilities in Java could use an overhaul, a *Project Papyrus* I would call it. And yes, part of that would be deprecating the `char`/`Character` type. Many years ago, I heard snickering remarks and jokes among the Java engineering team at Sun about the mess that is Java’s text and character handling, with its `char` type being broken by the Unicode expansion. Given other examples, such as the legacy date-time classes not yet deprecated despite having been supplanted years ago by *java.time*, it seems the decision to deprecate is not driven entirely by technical criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The numerical sum of chars `T & A` and `G & C` is fixed and unique for legal nucleobase pairs.  So you just need to ensure that the corresponding bases have one of those sums.

```
String seq1 = "TTCGATGGAGCTGTA";
String seq2 = "TAGCTAGCTCGGCATGA";
System.out.println(count_mismatches(seq1, seq2));
```

prints

```
5
```

- find max length to iterate
- establish fixed sums for comparison
- iterate and compare to expected pairing and update count appropriately

```
public static int count_mismatches(String seq1, String seq2) {
    int len1 = seq1.length();
    int len2 = seq2.length();
    int len = len1;
    if (len1 > len2) {
        len = len2;
    }
   
    int sumTA = 'T'+'A';
    int sumGC = 'G'+'C';
    
    int misMatchCount = Math.abs(len1-len2);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int pair = seq1.charAt(i) + seq2.charAt(i);
        if (pair != sumTA && pair != sumGC) {
            misMatchCount++;
        }
    }
    return misMatchCount;
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback on this.

Answer (score 0):

First you must find out which string is the shortest in length. Also you need to get the length difference when calculating the shortest string. After that, use that length as a terminating condition in your for loop. You can use booleans to check whether the values are present before incrementing the counter with an if statement.

The absolute value of any number can be obtained by calling the static method abs() from the Math class. Last, just add the mismatchCounts to the absolute value of the length difference in order to obtain the result.

Here is my solution.

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String seq1 = "TTCGATGGAGCTGTA";
    String seq2 = "TAGCTAGCTCGGCATGA";
    System.out.println(compareStrings(seq1, seq2));
}

public static int compareStrings(String stringOne, String stringTwo) {
    Character A = 'A', T = 'T', G = 'G', C = 'C';
    int mismatchCount = 0;
    int lowestStringLenght = 0;
    int length_one = stringOne.length();
    int length_two = stringTwo.length();
    int lenght_difference = 0;

    if (length_one < length_two) {// string one lenght is greater
        lowestStringLenght = length_one;
        lenght_difference = length_one - length_two;
    } else if (length_one > length_two) {// string two lenght is greater
        lowestStringLenght = length_two;
        lenght_difference = length_two - length_one;
    } else { // lenghts must be equal, use either
        lowestStringLenght = length_one;
        lenght_difference = 0; // there is no difference because they are equal
    }
   
    for (int i = 0; i < lowestStringLenght; i++) {
        // A matches with T
        // G matches with C
        // evaluate if the values A, T, G, C are present
        boolean A_T_PRESENT = stringOne.charAt(i) == A && stringTwo.charAt(i) == T;
        boolean G_C_PRESENT = stringOne.charAt(i) == G && stringTwo.charAt(i) == C;
        boolean T_A_PRESENT = stringOne.charAt(i) == T && stringTwo.charAt(i) == A;
        boolean C_G_PRESENT = stringOne.charAt(i) == C && stringTwo.charAt(i) == G;
        boolean TWO_EQUAL = stringOne.charAt(i) == stringTwo.charAt(i);

        // characters are equal, increase mismatch counter
        if (TWO_EQUAL) {
            mismatchCount++;
            continue;
        }
        // all booleans evaluated to false, it means that the characters are not proper
        // matches. Increment mismatchCount
        else if (!A_T_PRESENT && !G_C_PRESENT && !T_A_PRESENT && !C_G_PRESENT) {
            mismatchCount++;
            continue;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    // calculate the sum of the mismatches plus the abs of the lenght difference
    lenght_difference = Math.abs(lenght_difference);
    return mismatchCount + lenght_difference;
}
```

}